# UIImageView not loading image on all devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, ipad

This is my first time posting a questions here. So far I have been able to find the solution to all issues I have had. For 2 weeks now I'm struggling with a strange issue.

#### Issue Description:

I'm developing an universal application for iOS 5+. I'm having an issue with one image, which is not displayed everywhere. This is my background image and it displays correctly on all iPhones (3GS, 4, 4S, 5) and iPad retina. Unfortunately there are 3 screens on which it doesn't displays. This happens only on iPad without Retina display. The images appears on the other screens and I can't determine what is different so it doesn't display on these 3 screens.

#### What have I tested:

I have tried to delete the image and add it again - nothing changes.
I have double checked the naming of the file - everything is fine.
I have tried to load the image in another view controller and it loads.
I have cleaned my application and deleted it from all devices - issue stays.

If you happen to have any suggestions on what can be the cause of that strange behavior please give me a hint.

Comment: Did you check if the image for iPad is in the "Copy bundle resources" under build phases?

Comment: Any code on how you display these images??? Or you do it with XIBs??

Comment: Could you share the file names? Have you inspected the bundle contents of your compiled app and determined if the image is present? What happens at run time when you load the image path via `-[NSBundle pathForResource:...]`? What happens at run time when you load the image via `-[UIImage imageNamed:]`, and also `imageWithContentsOfFile:`?

Comment: @lostInTransit The image is in the "Copy bundle resources"

Comment: @satheeshwaran The image is positioned in the NIB and it is displayed there.

Comment: @CarlVeazey When I load the image with -[UIImage imageNamed:] it gets initialized. I have tried to programmatically add the image and it doesn't show ... I have an UIPopOverController and a UINavigationController in it if this will help.

Comment: So the image returned isn't nil, but when assigned to an image view's image property nothing shows?

Comment: Yes the Image is not nil. Also it displays on the listed devices but it doesn't display on iPad without Retina display. And I can't also change the background color of the View Controller

Comment: I bet you there's something wrong with the UIImageView. It's hidden or has its frame corrupted or something on retina iPad.

Comment: @CarlVeazey the issue appears only on no retina iPad. And the image appears in other ViewControllers. There are 3 UIViewControllers with UITableView's inside them, where the image does not appear. And I can't neither change the Background color of the UIView inside that UIViewController

Answer (score 0):

OK, since your image is already in the project and the target, here's a couple of other reasons which could cause the issue

1. The file extension and the type of file don't match. Try saving the in another format and use it in the app. See if that works
2. You mentioned this is a universal app? Are you naming the images correctly (image.png, image@2x.png, image~ipad.png and image@2x~ipad.png

Comment: The image is loaded in other 2 view controllers and it displays there. The naming conventions is correct. But the image is not displayed everywhere.